# Zend Framework: From a folder (not /)

Tags: php, iis, zend-framework

i notice that when i run a zend framework app from a server, there are alot of side effects. main issue is where i use urls like

```
/auth/login
```

i need to use

```
$this->baseUrl('/auth/login');
```

thats simple to fix. but when i use

```
$request->getRequestUri()
```

for use in redirects. eg after login, i want to redirect the user back to the prev page, it goes to the wrong place. eg. my app root is "http://localhost/app1", `$request->getRequestUri()` will give `/app1`. when i try to redirect back, it will goto http://localhost/app1/app1. btw, i am using Zend Server + IIS7 and my app is configured to run from the url stated above. maybe i shld be going to "/" instead. how can i resolve this?

## update

this is in my Zend_Form class

```
// (Zend_Form) Login.php init()
$req = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$returnUrl = $req->getParam('returnUrl', $req->getRequestUri());
$this->addElement('hidden', 'returnUrl', array(
    'value' => $returnUrl
));

// AuthController after login
$returnUrl = urldecode($form->getElement('returnUrl')->getValue());
if (!empty($returnUrl)) {
    $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')->setGotoUrl($returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: How does your redirect look like? That $request->getRequestUri() returns /app is expected behaviour.
Please ask your question more precise.

Comment: Post the code when you redirect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Zend_Application you can use this in your application.ini, and wont need to specify anything else.

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/your/public/path/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on you update:
Its the **prependBase**-Option in the Redirector what you are looking for:

> prependBase: boolean flag indicating whether or not to prepend the base URL when a relative URL is provided

So your fix is:

```
$this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')->setGotoUrl($returnUrl, array('prependBase' => false));
```

Comment: works like a charm. tho i am curious any reason to use `prependBase = true`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with help of Apache configs. In file \usr\local\apache\conf\vhosts.conf find a block with your site and change ways and public folder.

Comment: i am using iis now, i used apache b4 tho. i am trying out ZS with IIS, heard its faster